# Tensorflow: How to index a tensor using 2D-index like in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing, tensorflow

I would like to do the following numpy code in Tensorflow:

```
input = np.array([[1,2,3]
                  [4,5,6]
                  [7,8,9]])
index1 = [0,1,2]
index2 = [2,2,0]
output = input[index1, index2]
>> output
[3,6,7]
```

given an input such as:

```
input = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3],
                     [4, 5, 6],
                     [7, 8, 9]])
```

I have tried the following, but seems like an overshooting:

```
index3 = tf.range(0, input.get_shape()[0])*input.get_shape()[1] + index2
output = tf.gather(tf.reshape(input, [-1]), index3)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(output)
>> [3,6,7]
```

This works only because my first index is conveniently [0,1,2] but wouldn't be doable for [0,0,2] for example (besides looking really long and ugly).

Would you have any easier syntax, something more tensoric/pythonic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using `tf.gather_nd`[(tf.gather_nd official doc)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
inp = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9]])
res=tf.gather_nd(inp,list(zip([0,1,2],[2,2,0])))
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(res)
```

The result is `array([3, 6, 7])`

Answer (score 3):

How about using [tf.gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd)?

```
In [61]: input = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3],
    ...:                      [4, 5, 6],
    ...:                      [7, 8, 9]])

In [63]: row_idx = tf.constant([0, 1, 2])
In [64]: col_idx = tf.constant([2, 2, 0])
In [65]: coords = tf.transpose(tf.pack([row_idx, col_idx]))

In [67]: sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

In [68]: tf.gather_nd(input, coords).eval()
Out[68]: array([3, 6, 7], dtype=int32)
```